# HTTP 407 while attempting to get dependencies using dep

Tags: go

I am trying to work on a Go open source project, on a corporate device. Attempts to address the dependencies via `dep ensure` command always return `407 PROXY AUTH required`. I do have `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variable set with values in the format `http://user:pasword@proxyname:proxyport`. I have also attempted to set the `git` configs `http.proxy`. But I do get the same error. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I am using the `dep` library here and not the `godep` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is owing to Git client configuration issues and mismatch between git binary and gnutls. I have had to recompile git binary using openssl, to get this to work.